# Print all session/post/get variables in ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net, session, variables, session-variables

I am very new to ASP.NET, I'm quite used to PHP (which we unfortunately do not use at work)
I'd like to print all the session variables. In PHP it's quite easy, I use:

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($_SESSION, true) . '</pre>';
```

for this, but is there an as-easy ASP.NET equivalent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

with box being a label.

```
foreach (string i in Session.Contents) {
  if (Session[i] != null) {
    box.Text += i + " = " + Session[i].ToString() + "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: make a label or literal with the id=box.

Comment: sorry for this newbie question. I saved your code in .php file, and absolutely I got an error. Then I've tried to saved that at .aspx file. but what happen is that it only printed all the code. All I know is PHP, do I need to add tag before I add that code in aspx file? in php we have to add <?php ?> what about the aspx?

Answer (score 6):

Your easiest route is to just enable tracing. This will show you all of this information automatically. You can do this at the page, or the application level.

Here is a [quick tutorial](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Tracing-ASP.NET.aspx) on getting started.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`HttpRequest.Params`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.params.aspx):

> Gets a combined collection of QueryString, Form, ServerVariables, and Cookies items.